# How to use basepath for certain pages in NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am developing an NextJS application and I'm using version 13.
My question is how to set the basepath for certain pages only.

For example:

> "/auth/*" --> not to show basepath

> "/remaining-pages" --> show basepath "/app"

This is my next.config.js file:

```js
const nextConfig = {
  experimental: {
    appDir: true,
  },
  basePath: "/app",
};
```

I tried with the rewrites config

```js
async rewrites() {
  return [
    {
      source: '/app/auth/login',
      destination: '/auth/login',
    },
  ]
}
```

and also if I give basepath to rewrite I'm getting a error

```
Invalid rewrite return
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`basePath` was removed from Next.js 13 so it's not available to the `/app` folder, unfortunately. There's an alternative on the roadmap which is not yet implemented.

https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/upgrade-guide#step-5-migrating-routing-hooks

You would need to use the `/pages` directory for your `auth` folder in order to take advantage of the `basePath` property from the `stable` documentation.

Comment: Hi Wesley, I did try that but still the same. It was working only if I gave the basepath.

Comment: Interesting.

I see on the experimental interface that the `manualClientBasePath` boolean option exists. I don't see any documentation on that though.

I will create a sandbox and test it out - I am still learning Next.js13 so I'm not sure if the baseUrl stops working when experimental is set.

Comment: I don't think basePath was removed from Next.js 13 (I'm using it in v13.4.9), but there were some issues that seem to be fixed now (https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/41824)